# How can I parse json data as array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have an object.

```
[Object { id=8,  question="وصلت المنافذ الجمركية في...طنة حتّى عام 1970م إلى ",  choice1="20 منفذًا",  more...}, Object { id=22,  question="تأسست مطبعة مزون التي تع... الأولى في السلطنة عام ",  choice1="1959م",  more...}, Object { id=3,  question="فنّان،تخصص في نقش محاريب...حراب مسجد المكبر في نخل",  choice1="طالب بن مشمل المنحي",  more...}, Object { id=10,  question="استمرت المطبعة السلطانية...ة الحكم العماني بها سنة",  choice1="1961م",  more...}, Object { id=15,  question="أصوله من أدم،انتقل مع أس...لم الحكم خلفا له،اغتيل.",  choice1="صالح بن محمد المنذري",  more...}, Object { id=28,  question="مؤلف كتاب " حقائق الإيمان"",  choice1="سعيد بن خلفان الخليلي ",  more...}, Object { id=25,  question="من آثاره العلمية كتاب "ا...ديان والأحكام" (مخطوط).",  choice1="عبدالله بن حميد السالمي",  more...}, Object { id=6,  question="زعيم سياسي. ولد في بلدة ...اته عام 1407هـ (1987م) ",  choice1="صالح بن علي الحارثي",  more...}, Object { id=21,  question="تأسست المطبعة السلطانية ...كومية الأولى بعمان عام ",  choice1="1958م",  more...}, Object { id=13,  question="تأسّست مطبعة النجاح وهي ...الأولى، في زنجبارسنة:  ",  choice1="1912م",  more...}]
```

This is stored in data.questions. Each element is an object. What do I do so that I can have its questions as an array? Please help me guys. I am stucked. I tried many ways but it is not working.

**UPDATE**

I am requesting my JSON data from [here](http://omanknowledge.com/marifa/getMultipleChoiceQuestions.php?noOfQuestions=10). I want this data inside a simple array which I can process.

Comment: What ways did you try?

Comment: Methods from other stack overflow answers, but they are not of the same format as my data.

Comment: I am a little confused as to expected output. Could you provide a small example of expected output. So what do you want, the content from question= , choice1= ...?

Comment: Please mention some of your implemented code here.

Comment: your update asks an entirely different question, open a new question instead

Comment: Thats confusing. Were not here to spend our time interpreting questions. Please provide your code, and what went wrong. Than we can help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Iterate through the objects and store the data in an array

```
var questions = JSON.parse(/*put your json string in here*/);
var arr = [];

for (var x in questions) {
    arr.push(questions[x].question);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 var finalOutput = [];
    $.each(data.questions, function(i, d) {
        finalOutput.push({question : d.question},{choice1 : d.choice1},{choice2 : d.choice2},{choice3 : d.choice3},{choice4 : d.choice4},{correctanswer  : d.correctanswer });                      
    });
```

**JS Bin link** : 
http://jsbin.com/siwiyi/edit?js,console

Comment: There is not just question, there are choice1, choice2, choice3 and choice4 as well inside the object.

Comment: I want question, choice1, choice2, choice3, choice4, correctanswer as well. All the data.

Comment: I want to access each question like finalOutput[0].question, finalOutput[0].choice1, finalOutput[0].choice2. Not like finalOutput[0], finalOutput[1]. Any ideas?

Comment: You can access your data in a similar fashion if you want to get 1st set of data you can access it like finalOutput[0].question, finalOutput[0].choice1, finalOutput[0].choice2 and so on

Answer (score 0):

```
var inputarray=[.....];
var questionarray=[];
for(i=0;i<inputarray.length;i++){
    questionarray.push(inputarray[i].question);
}
```

Comment: If you wanna load it dynamicly, check AJAX or Curl (php). Its not that difficult to find

Answer (score 0):

Use the functional [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) method to pull out all the object keys and `.map` to place the values inside an array

```
Object.keys(obj).map(key => obj[key]);
```

You can also use the experimental [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) method to get the values

**EDIT**

Because your data is made out of objects inside an array, you can use a `.forEach` or `.map` to iterate over them

```
data.questions.map(obj => {
    return Object.keys(obj).map(key => obj[key]);
})
```

This will provide you an array of your needed objects

Answer (score 0):

Aleksv's answer does it. Optionally you can use `map` function:

```js
var objectsArray = [
  { id:8,  question:"وصلت المنافذ الجمركية في...طنة حتّى عام 1970م إلى ",  choice1:"20 منفذًا"},
  { id:22,  question:"تأسست مطبعة مزون التي تع... الأولى في السلطنة عام ",  choice1:"1959م"},
  { id:3,  question:"فنّان،تخصص في نقش محاريب...حراب مسجد المكبر في نخل",  choice1:"طالب بن مشمل المنحي"}];

var questionsArray = objectsArray.map(function(item){
  return item.question;
});//

console.log( questionsArray );
```

Comment: what about the choices?

Comment: @AliZia You said you want the 'questions' as an array. This solution and some others pick the question from each object in the array. It does not matter that those objects have other properties e.g. `choices`.